# How can we reconcile the supposed contradiction in the above texts in 2 Kings 15:30 & 2 Kings 17:1?

Tags: contradiction, 2-kings

(KJV) 2 Kings 15:30

> 30 And Hoshea the son of Elah made a conspiracy against Pekah the son of Remaliah, and smote him, and slew him, and reigned in his stead, in the twentieth year of Jotham the son of Uzziah.

(KJV) 2 Kings 17:1

> 1 In the twelfth year of Ahaz king of Judah began Hoshea the son of Elah to reign in Samaria over Israel nine years

In the above text Hoshea is supposed to have started reigning in twentieth year of Jotham which so happens to be the fourth year of Ahaz's reigns.

But in the other text Hoshea started reigning in the twelth year of Ahaz's reign.

How can we reconcile the apparent contraction?

Comment: On [one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pekah#Controversy) hand. On the [other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kings_of_Judah#Co-regency) hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jotham reigned for sixteen years, so twenty years after his reign began, is the same as the fourth year of his son Ahaz's reign.

> Benson Commentary
>   2 Kings 15:30. Hosea made a conspiracy against Pekah, and smote him — It is probable that the people were provoked at him for leaving them exposed to a foreign enemy, while he invaded Judah; and that Hosea took advantage of their discontent and disgust to seize and slay him. Thus Pekah’s treason and violence returned upon himself at last.
>
> *And reigned in his stead in the twentieth year of Jotham — The meaning is, that he began his reign in the twentieth year after the beginning of Jotham’s reign; or, which is the same thing, in the fourth year of Ahaz, son of Jotham.*

[**Biblehub - Benson's Commentary**](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/2_kings/15-30.htm)

Answer (score -1):

## You can't

You must not only must match 1st year of Hoshea, 20th year (out of 16) of Jotam (which is fine, given Jotam was regent for a while for his father), and 12th year of Akhas, but you also must match 17th year of Peka to 1ast year of Akhas, and 20th year of Peka to 1st year of Hoshea!

With these numbers the task is impossible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The community bot says it needs sources, but I believe this answer mostly needs a little more explanation. Albeit, I don't agree with the answer. But, I support answers I disagree with as long as they are well-prepared. I'd like to see a little more explanation so the user's point is clearer.